# Trigger SelectedIndex changed whilst clicking on any control within a ListBoxItem area

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview

I've a data template for ListBoxItem which contains of few buttons, and few custom controls like Grid or Chart. Each button is bound to an appropriate command handler,  SelectedIndex property of a ListView control is bound to ViewModel's propery as well.

**The problem**: in command handlers (which are bound to buttons) I can't resolve currently selected item/index because it is not changing whilst clicking on a button or an other control within a ListBox item, but when I clicking on ListBoxItem area itself - SelectedIndex is changing.

**Question is** how to trigger SelectedIndex to be changed whilst clicking on any control within ListBoxItem?

Comment: Can't you just get parent of the Button object as ListBoxItem and check for its index?

Comment: If you just need to find the item that's been clicked on (and actually have no direct requirement to change the selected item) then you're going about this entirely the wrong way.  If you structured your code better then you'd not need to use SelectedIndex at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your `ListBox.Resources`

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

**EDIT**

The previous method only makes the ListBoxItem selected for as long as it has keyboard focus. If you move focus out of the ListBoxItem, it becomes unselected again.

Here's another simple way to select a ListBox item when the keyboard focus moves within the item, and it stays selected when focus is moved out of the ListBoxItem

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <EventSetter Event="PreviewGotKeyboardFocus" Handler="SelectCurrentItem"/>
</Style>
```

And in the Code Behind

```
protected void SelectCurrentItem(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem item = (ListBoxItem)sender;
    item.IsSelected = true;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution, for a similar problem. the item is being highlighted correctly but when i try to access the listbox.selectedItem it is set to null and the selectedindex is -1 :S

Comment: @Marcom You're right, I never noticed that. I posted another alternative which is still fairly simple, but it updates the SelectedIndex/Item

Comment: Thanks Rachel, this is what I'am looking for

Answer (score 1):

Can you not set the item as the selected item in the bound command?  If your list Item viewmodel has access to whatever the ListBoxes viewmodel is, you should be able to set the property that you have bound there.

```
Private Sub ButtonClickExecute()
     ListBoxVM.SelectedItem = Me.MyModelItem
End Sub
```

I have done this on occasion and it has worked quite well, so long as the SelectedItem bound property is read/write, PropertyChangeNotification is working.

If your ViewModel and Model don't support this, let me know and we can try another way.

Whoops, did not immediately notice the C# tag.  That should be:

```
ListBoxVM.selectedItem = this.myModelItem;
```

Comment: Really I'm not selecting an item in command handler, I just using SelectedIndex to access the selected item and process it. it would be great if it is possible to do it in xaml without code behind, but this is not a restriction

Comment: Well the command that the button is bound to resides in the ViewModel for the ListViewItem right?  If so, you should be able to pass the View (a ListViewItem) to the viewModel SelectedItem bound property for the ListView to set the item as selected.  When you click the button, you know which item is selected.  You just have to tell the ListView which it is.  There is likely a way to trickledown the focus from the button to the ListViewItem so that it handles the selection itself, but I never found out how, so I employed this method.  Works well, is simple, and can be used for many things.

Comment: Or are you talking about button command bindings that are in a ViewModel other than the ListViewItems?

Comment: All is right, button is bound to command which resides in the underlying ViewModel of ListView. I got your idea and will try it if not find anything another because in this case I have to change some ViewModel's logic to set manually SelectedItem, there are a lot of things around SelectedIndex and SelectedItem so I won't touch it as long as possible, anyway thanks I'll continue investigation and nothing was found - will try your solution and write down here is results

Comment: +1 I've not found any solution with XAML only so used approach you've proposed - pass selected item as command parameter, but anyway I still looking for some more universal solution which cover all controls like Grid and Chart withoud manually attached comman for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

XAML-only solution:

You can adapt the ItemContainerStyle and listen on the trigger is the mousefocus is inside of the Item. It works for all kind of child elements (in this example just mouse focus, which shouldnt be a problem, as the keyboard selects the item automatically too...)

example:

```
  <Grid>  
    <Grid.Resources>
      <x:Array x:Key="strings" Type="sys:String" >
        <sys:String>test</sys:String>
        <sys:String>test</sys:String>
        <sys:String>test</sys:String>
        <sys:String>test</sys:String>
      </x:Array>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="ContainerStyle">     
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter />
          </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
      <Style.Triggers>         
      <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">          
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
      </Trigger>     
      </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource strings}}"  ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ContainerStyle}" >
  <ListBox.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="x:Type ListBoxItem">
    <ListBoxItem IsSelected="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" />
  </DataTemplate>

  </ListBox.Resources>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
      <Button Content="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: How to adopt this XAML to handle left mouse clicks?

Comment: you dont have to. as you click on a button the keyboardfocus is set on the button inside the item and so the item gets selected...

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in the item 'underneath' the data template you can use a CommandParameter with a the binding as a argument.

CommandParameter={Binding}

This will pass the current item as a parameter to the command, so no need to track the selected item.