# wpf selecting controls inside a listbox

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox

I have a textbox and some labels inside the data template of bounded listbox.

When I click on any label the whole item is highlighted in blue, but when I click directly on a different textbox the selection does not change.

Is there a way to make the selection of the listbox change even when a textbox is clicked?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF: Trigger SelectedIndex changed whilst clicking on any control within a ListBoxItem area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680987/wpf-trigger-selectedindex-changed-whilst-clicking-on-any-control-within-a-listbo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've exactly asked few days ago, see post: ["WPF: Trigger SelectedIndex changed whilst clicking on any control within a ListBoxItem area"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6680987/485076)

basically there are few solutions, using code behind and XAML, but I've not verified latter approach yet

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the TextBox handles the click event in order to receive focus.  There are a number of ways to handle this, including but not limited to:

- stop the TextBox handling mouse events (which prevents the user from focussing it using the mouse)
- use an eventhandler when the TextBox gains focus (or PreviewClick or similar), to select the parent ListItem