# How to associate button to ListView.SelectedItem

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, listview, mvvm

I have a ListView ItemsSource bound to an ObservableCollection.  I added a property via MVVM to track the ListView.SelectedItem.  A button was added to my ListView (via GridViewColumn.CellTemplate) to create a button command which displays data regarding each object in my ObservableCollection.  So the list of objects in my ObservableCollection (ListView column 1) is shown in the ListView with a corresponding button (ListView column 2).

The Code works great! The only problem: the user must click the ListView row before clicking the corresponding button in the list.  (I get a null reference exception on my "SelectedFromQueue" property if the user clicks the button without clicking the ListView row first.)

I would like to add code which sets the ListView.SelectedItem property when a button is clicked. So, if the user clicks a button, the code should update the ListView.SelectedItem property binding before the associated MVVM command is executed.

Does someone have any example code for this?  Thanks for your help.

My XAML:

```
<UserControl xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             x:Class="MyApp.QueueObjectList"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="290" Width="320">

    <Grid Width="319">
        <GroupBox Header="Queue Class List" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="319" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=QueueList}" Name="QueueListView">
                <ListView.SelectedItem>
                    <Binding Path="SelectedFromQueue" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                    </Binding>               
                </ListView.SelectedItem>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="140" Header="Queue Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Width="179" Header="Property Information">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Content="Get Property Info" Command="{Binding Path=GetQueueObjProperties}"
                                        DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" />                      
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

My MainWindowViewModel C# Code:

```cs
private ObservableCollection<Queue> _QueueList;
private Queue _selectedFromQueue;

public ObservableCollection<Queue> QueueList
{
    get { return _QueueList; }
    set
    {
        _QueueList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("QueueList");
    }
}

public Queue SelectedFromQueue
{
    get { return _selectedFromQueue; }
    set
    {
        _selectedFromQueue= value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedFromQueue");
    }
}

// Constructor
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    QueueList = new ObservableCollection<Queue>();
    _selectedFromQueue= null;
}

public ICommand GetQueueObjProperties
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(GetQueueProperties, CanGetQueueProperties); }
}

private bool CanGetQueueProperties()
{
    if (_QueueList.Count > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void GetQueueProperties()
{
    if (CanGetQueueProperties())
    {
        ResponseMessage.Add("Queue name: " +SelectedFromQueue.Name);
    }
}
```

---

Update:
Thanks sll!

I added the following to my XAML code:

```
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewGotKeyboardFocus" Handler="SelectCurrentItem"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
```

I added the following c# method to code behind:

```
        protected void SelectCurrentItem(Object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)sender;
            item.IsSelected = true;
        }
```

Works great!
Thanks again for the reference sll!

Comment: I've asked the same before, check out this question perhaps solution provided by Rachel will help you: WPF: [Trigger SelectedIndex changed whilst clicking on any control within a ListBoxItem area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680987/wpf-trigger-selectedindex-changed-whilst-clicking-on-any-control-within-a-listb)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `GetQueueProperties` does, but it sounds that you use `SelectedFromQueue`
 to know on what item to execute your logic and the selection in GUI is secondary.

If that's the case, don't use `SelectedFromQueue` but add this to the `Button`:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"
```

This will give you a `Queue` object associated with the row of the pressed button as `e.Parameter` in `SelectedFromQueue`.

If you *do* need to set selected item for the GUI, at the start of `SelectedFromQueue` add:

```
SelectedFromQueue = (e.Parameter is Queue) ? e.Parameter : null
```

Comment: Thanks XAMeLi
Note the new code I added to this post.  I added a new ListView.Resource to access the EventSetter for the ListView.  The event handler links to a new c# method in the code behind. The c# method SelectCurrentItem sets the "IsSelected" property to true when the user hovers the mouse over any row in the ListView. Now, my users can simply click a button associated to the row and access corresponding object from the ObservableCollection.