# Select ListView Element on button Click using MVVM

Tags: mvvm

I have one list as RoomGroupList and another as RooList,One Room Group have multiple Roos in it, like

RoomGroup 1 => Room-1
               Room-2
               Room-3

I have bound RoomGroupList to ListView and RoomGroupControll is Generating From it as,

```
<ListView x:Name="lstRoomGroupList" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding roomGroupList,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                                                                                                                     SelectedItem="{Binding evokoRoomGroup,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                                    **<UserConrols:RoomGroupControl/>**
                                                                </DataTemplate>
                                                            </ListView.ItemTemplate
```

Now RoomGroupControl has one ListView to Listout No.ofRooms in it as,

```
 <ListView x:Name="lstRoomList" Grid.Row="3"  ItemsSource="{Binding GetroomList,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                                             SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.EvokoRoom,ElementName=tbDashBoard,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                                             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#F3F3F5" 
                                                                             BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0"
                                                                             Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="Auto" MaxHeight="200" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        **<UserConrols:RoomControl/>**
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

what I want is,when I click on any button from ListElements at that time it's corresponding ListItem(row) should be selected so that I have added EventSetter using Resource on RoomGroupList as

```
<ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewGotKeyboardFocus"   Handler="SelectCurrentItem"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
```

It's working properly for RoomGroupList I'm able to select Different Groups but Problem is I Can't select Rooms From RoomGroup which I have selected.

If anyone knows how to manage this, can also provide me Links and Suggestions,Thanks.

Comment: I have applied same code on RoomGroupList using Resources  inside RoomGroupControl but it's not working :(

I have referred this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053120/how-to-associate-button-to-listview-selecteditem

Comment: found the problem,was my mistake, I have not set SelectionMode="Single" at RoomList and also we don't need to put <ListView.Resources> in RoomList it works without it.