# How can I get an event or command to fire when the user clicks on a ListViewItem?

Tags: wpf

I have a list in my application's UI and I'd like to open a popover when the user clicks on an item in the list. As far as I can tell, there are no `Click` events on `ListViewItem` that will help me with this. The `SelectionChanged` event will not work either, since the user can close the popover and I'd like to be able to open it again without requiring them to select a different item in the list first.

This is what my `ListView` creation code looks like, for what it's worth:

```
<ListView x:Name="_resultsListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableResults}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedResult}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LoadResultItemStyle}"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          Style="{DynamicResource DefaultListViewStyle}" BorderThickness="0"/>
```

Thanks! Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What [HB suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11267278/302677) works, although I find a more permanent solution for binding `Events` to `Commands` is to use an [AttachedCommandBehavior](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/) that will let you attach a command to just about any event

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Event" Value="Click" />
    <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, ElementName=MyListView}" />
    <Setter Property="local:CommandBehavior.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding }" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a `Button` in the `ItemTemplate` (or `ListViewItem.Template` set via the `ItemContainerStyle`) and bind it to a command, you can style it to be invisible if need be.

Comment: One problem with this is that when I click on the Button, the item does not become selected. Is there a way to get the Button to fire its Command and also have the ListViewItem become selected?

Comment: @Greg You can use a Trigger to set `IsSelected` based on `IsKeyboardFocusWithin`. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6752690/302677) for more details